# find() doesn't return data, only undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, find

I want to find() s_id form this JSON:

```
 {
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "StatusMessage": "OK",
        "StatusDescription": [
             {
                "s_id": "11E8C70C8A5D78888E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "PkMGo",
                "active": 0,
              },
             {
                "s_id": "11E8C70FB9D10DB38E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "UgooX",
                "active": 0,
                },
              {
                "s_id": "11E8C7179F85836D8E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "IiLnM",
                "active": 0,
                }, .....
            {
                "s_id": "11E8C71905123F1A8E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "LVpcP",
                "active": 0,
             }
              }]}
```

I try to find in this but return undefined.

```
 sensors: Sensors[]=[];
 hbp: HBP;
 sensor: Sensors;

     this.ss.getAllS().subscribe(
          sensors => {
            this.sensors = sensors 
            let ss = this.sensors.find(x => x.s_id ===  this.hbp.s_id);
            console.log(ss)
            if (ss) {
              this.selectedSensor = ss.s_id
            }
          }
        );
```

and

```
 selectedSensor : string = this.sensors.filter(
    x => x.s_id === this.sensor.s_id[0])
    .map(y => y.s_serial).join('');
```

I think that I have problem in this line:

```
        let ss = this.sensors.find(x => x.s_id ===  this.hbp.s_id);
```

because, hbp return this json:

```
active: 0
homebox_id: "11E8C71154CC8C188E6EFA163EBBBC1D"
sensors: Array(2)
0: {s_serial: "s_id", s_id: "11E8C70C8A5D78888E6EFA163EBBBC1D"}
1: {s_serial: "UgooX", s_id: "11E8C70FB9D10DB38E6EFA163EBBBC1D"}
```

and in this line maybe will find inside this sensors

This   `selectedSensor`  I used in html code

```
<input formControlName="s_id" type="text" placeholder="Select " [(ngModel)]="selectedSensor" aria-label="Number" matInput
            [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

How to return data ?

Can you ask me any idea please?

Comment: Updated the answer , please check. Stackblitz also updated

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `find` function like below

```
  let ss =   this.sensors.find((item) => {
      return item.s_id === this.hbp.s_idl
    })


if (ss) {
    this.selectedSensor = ss.s_id         
      }
```

If you are looking for filter,map and join combination , Please make sure you are returning the item.property inside **map**

```
.filter((item) => {
  return item.s_id ===  ss.s_id
}).map(
  (item) => {
    return item.s_serial
  }
).join( )
```

Check this sample code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/arrayfind?file=index.js

Comment: .find() does not return an array. It returns the first value that matches the condition. .filter() returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me, are you sure that `this.ss.getAllS()` method returns an array of StatusDescription types? I would recommend to debug what is actually in `sensors` variable at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The observable: sensors, will initially be null, and you can't access properties of null to compare anything to.

Instead, do a quick null check on the sensors value, then do your find operation:

```
this.ss.getAllS().subscribe(sensors => {
  if (sensors) {
    this.selectedSensor = this.sensors.find(x => x.s_id === this.hbp.s_id)
  }
});
```

Here's a StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-id-from-observable

Comment: OP applied the find function after subscribe the observable , So sensors will not be null I think

Comment: It depends on the type of Observable. If it's a Subject, it will initially be null. If it's a BehaviorSubject it won't.

Comment: I add more details in my post. Thank you for your answer!